# Select most Occurred Value SQL with Inner Join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this query to get the following data from different linked tables. But let's say the `VENDORS` for an item were three. Now here in result i want to show the Vendor which occurred most. I mean if Item `ABC` was supplied by 3 different vendors many times. Then here i want to get the Vendor who supplied most of the times item ABC.

My query is this.

```
use iBusinessFlex;
SELECT Items.Name, 
Max(Items.ItemID) as ItemID ,
MAX(Items.Description)as Description,
MAX(ItemsStock.CurrentPrice) as UnitPrice,
MAX(ItemsStock.Quantity) as StockQuantiity,
MAX(Vendors.VendorName) as VendorName, 
SUM(ItemReceived.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
From ItemReceived  
INNER JOIN Items ON ItemReceived.ItemId=Items.ItemID 
INNER JOIN ItemsStock ON ItemReceived.ItemId=ItemsStock.ItemID 
INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices ON PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceId = ItemReceived.PurchaseInvoiceId 
INNER JOIN Vendors ON Vendors.VendorId = PurchaseInvoices.VendorId
Group By Items.Name
```

**EDIT : I have included this sub query but i am not sure if it is showing correct result. i mean Showing Vendor for each Item who provided that item most of the times**

```
use iBusinessFlex;
SELECT Items.Name,
Max(Items.ItemID) as ItemID ,
MAX(Items.Description)as Description,MAX(ItemsStock.CurrentPrice) as UnitPrice,
MAX(ItemsStock.Quantity) as StockQuantiity,MAX(Vendors.VendorName) as VendorName, 
SUM(ItemReceived.Quantity) as TotalQuantity
From ItemReceived  
INNER JOIN Items ON ItemReceived.ItemId=Items.ItemID INNER JOIN ItemsStock 
ON ItemReceived.ItemId=ItemsStock.ItemID INNER JOIN PurchaseInvoices 
ON PurchaseInvoices.PurchaseInvoiceId = ItemReceived.PurchaseInvoiceId INNER JOIN Vendors
ON Vendors.VendorId IN (
SELECT Top 1 MAX(PurchaseInvoices.VendorId) as VendorOccur
FROM PurchaseInvoices INNER JOIN Vendors ON Vendors.VendorId=PurchaseInvoices.VendorId
GROUP BY PurchaseInvoices.VendorId
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

And the Result Looks like this.
[image: Result of this query Image]

[image: VendorsTable]

Comment: Please edit your question and show clear sample input and output data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i have attached image ! it's not showing here but link is attached please see

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen sir any help please ? :(

Comment: what do you mean by vendor who supplied the most item? Is it the vendor with highest total quantity or something else?

Comment: @peeyushsingh the vendor who supplied ABC item more times then any other !

Comment: so the vendor who have the most invoices with item ABC? Its not clear how to define vendor who supplied ABC on the basis of information you have given.

Comment: Yes ! and i have attached Vendor Table !

Comment: in your image link, I see that there are only 2 Vendor Names. And all the item names are unique. Can you publish the sample dataset of the tables provided in join conditions? It'll help us analyse the issue better

Comment: @KrishnaKarthik yes data shown is result od above query i have mentioned ! i am selecting the distict items and there some other properties and Vendor who provided !

Comment: Images of data aren't helpful. We can't use use it. If you want to post data, post it as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. That result set is for the query you have, which appears to not be what you're adter so it's actually not giving us any information we need at all. We need to know what your data looks like **before** your query, and what you want it to look like after.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand the question correctly. But can you do a `GROUP BY` in an outer query on `itemID` and `ORDER BY` maybe `COUNT(VendorName)`?

Comment: @Larnu sir the sample data is in thousands records and each table have about 20 columns ..can i show that here anyhow ? i just fetching the Distinct Items data and some relevant data from linked tables that also include VENDOR of that item. Now Vendors can be many of same item. i just want to show the vendor who provided item ABC most times !

Comment: A sample doesn't include all the data; that's why it's called a "sample".

Comment: @NicholasHumphrey i think you are close sir ! i have tried this and it shows the result but i myslef not sure if this is right result ! means the vendor shown for each item is the one who providded it most times .PLEASE SEE EDITS !

Comment: You don't need to provide thousands of rows but you do need to provide some example data. What you have here currently is "Here is my query that does not produce the correct results, and here are those incorrect results. How do I fix it?". Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some ideas on what you need to post.

Comment: @SeanLange sir i have tried best to explain my question :(

Comment: But th explaination isn't enough; hence why we need the sample data and expected result. Without it we can only guess. Help us help you; provide what we've asked and I'm sure any number of the volunteers will be able to help you. Without it, none of us can.

Comment: You have explained it. But you haven't provided any sample data so that others can actually help you. You see we can't just take a result set that is wrong and a query that is wrong and magically fix it. I actually ignore data when it is incorrect.  Why bother looking at it? For the type of problem here I can think of at least 3 or 4 ways to tackle it but they are all somewhat dependent on what you are actually trying to accomplish. Maybe ROW_NUMBER? Maybe TOP?

Comment: @SeanLange SIR THE QUERY IS NOT WRONG !!! THE RESULT IS VALID . But only change i want is that i want the VENDOR WHO SUPPLIED SPECIFIC ITEM MOST TIMES !

Comment: I am trying to help you, screaming at me is not a good way to get my assistance. Maybe you need to use COUNT? Providing the desired output would go a LONG way to making this more clear.

Comment: @SeanLange  ia m not screaming honestly ! i am really a lot thankful to all the people trying to help here ! i am sorry if you got any impression like that .. :(

Comment: Typing in all caps is screaming. But whatever...this query is really not that difficult but without specifics it is impossible. Post the desired output as data, not a textual explanation. I just can't figure out what you are really trying to do here.

Comment: *"ia m not screaming"* what do you think something like "*PLEASE SEE MY EDITS!"* is other than screaming? It's all in capitals and followed by an exclamation mark. That is exactly how you shout at someone in textual dialogue.

Comment: @Larnu Honestly i was not ! it's just me i guess i write in caps to highlight something. not screaming. i wrote in caps to highlight that i have edited the question and have added something please check that. :(

Answer (score 1):

First, I would start with who ordered what thing the most.  But the MOST is based on what... the most quantity?  Price?, Number of Times?  If you use one vendor and order 6 times qty of 10 you have 60 things. But order 1 time from another vendor for 100 qty, which one wins.   You have to decide the basis of MOST, but I will go based on most times
per your original question.

So all things come from PurchasedInvoices which has a vendor ID.  I dont care who the vendor is, just their ID, so no need to join.  Also, don't need the item name if I am just looking for my counts.  The query below will show per item, each vendor and their respective most times ordered and quantities ordered.  I added the items and vendor table joins just to show the names.

```
select
        IR.ItemID,
        PI.VendorID,
        max( I.Name ) Name,
        max( V.VendorName ) VendorName,
        count(*) as TimesOrderedFrom,
        SUM( IR.Quantity ) as QuantityFromVendor
    from
        ItemsReceived IR
            JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI
                on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
            JOIN Items I
                on IR.ItemID = I.ItemID
            JOIN Vendors V
                on IR.VendorID = V.VendorID
    group by
        IR.ItemID,
        PI.VendorID
    order by
        -- Per item
        IR.ItemID,
        -- Most count ordered
        count(*),
        -- If multiple vendors, same count, get total quantity
        sum( IR.Quantity )
```

Now, to get only 1 per item, this would create a correlated subquery and you 
can add 'TOP 1' to return only the first by this.  Since the aggregate of count
is already done, you can then get the vendor contact info.

```
select
        I.Name,
        V.VendorName,
        TopVendor.TimesOrderedFromVendor,
        TopVendor.QuantityFromVendor
    from
        Items I
            JOIN ( select TOP 1
                            IR.ItemID,
                            PI.VendorID,
                            count(*) as TimesOrderedFrom,
                            SUM( IR.Quantity ) as QuantityFromVendor
                        from
                            ItemsReceived IR
                                JOIN PurchaseInvoices PI
                                    on IR.PurchaseInvoiceID = PI.PurchaseInvoiceID
                        where
                            -- correlated subquery based on the outer-most item
                            IR.ItemID = I.ItemID
                        group by
                            IR.ItemID,
                            PI.VendorID
                        order by
                            -- Per item
                            IR.ItemID,
                            -- Most count ordered
                            count(*),
                            -- If multiple vendors, same count, get total quantity
                            sum( IR.Quantity ) ) TopVendor
                on I.ItemID = TopVendor.ItemID
                JOIN Vendors V
                    on TopVendor.VendorID = V.VendorID
```

No sense in having the INNER Subquery joining on the vendor and items just for the names.  Get those once and only at the end when the top vendor is selected.

Comment: HI sir ! really thanks for your time . i just want to show end result in a way that i showed in first picture with the change that in vendor column it should show the VENDOR who provided MOSTQuantity of that particular item !

Comment: and second query is not returning the CORRECT VENDOR who provided most quantity ! if you can please check that ?

Comment: can you please correct second query to get the vendor who provided the most quantity of a particular item ?

Comment: @Hammas_stack2, just change the last query the ORDER BY clause.  Instead of COUNT(*) before the SUM(), make it SUM(), then COUNT(*).  This forces the highest SUM QUANTITY to the top instead of highest COUNT.